# Breaking centred words whilst keeping document outline intact

Tags: html, css

I have the following code

```css
h2 {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h2>Example<br/>text</h2>
```

The document outline displays the heading like "Exampletext" and I would like it to appear as "Example text".

I initially added a space like

```
 <h2>Some <br/>text</h2>
```

This corrects the document outline but throws off the centering visually.

Is there an easy way to achieve what I want?

### Update

Here is a 
[visual example showing the centering issue with the document outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfKE4.jpg) I'm using a google chrome extension called HTML5 outliner to generate the document outline.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't do what you claim it does.

Comment: word-wrap: break-word;

Comment: @j08691 please explain. Here is an example https://codepen.io/itsdannylalala/pen/xrxKdb add a space after the word "Some" and you will see the centering go out of line.

Comment: @techLove please explain, I've tried `word-wrap:break-word` doesn't give the desired result either.

Comment: i am confused now what you are trying to achieve. if you need space just use <h2>Example text</h2>

Comment: The code pen example above gives me what I need visually. However if you generate a document outline using the example then it will generate "Sometext" I want to seperate the two words in the document outline whilst not changing how it appears visually

Comment: can you share link of document outliner you are using

Comment: Updated the question with an image showing the problem

Comment: Could you just give them each separate h2 tags then?

Comment: No because they would then have their own entry in the outline it would look like 1. Some 2. entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the space after the `<br/>` tag accomplishes what I want, posting here as others could potentially benefit in future.